# How to manage multiple configuration for vim?

Tags: vim

I am currently working with multiple projects which have different vim setting required. Is there a way to open vim with specific configuration file ?

Comment: It is enough for your needs `vim -u {vimrc}` ?  From man vim:  `All the other initializations are skipped. Use this to edit a special kind of files...   See ":help initialization" within vim for more details.`

Comment: [so] question [Multiple vim configurations?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/1889602)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Search for plugins like [local_vimrc](https://github.com/LucHermitte/local_vimrc) -- I give a short list of alternatives at the end of the README

NB: This is a recurring question:

- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456792/vim-apply-settings-on-files-in-directory/
- https://vi.stackexchange.com/questions/2094/how-to-make-vimrc-settings-applicable-for-a-directory-tree-only/
- ...